# Firebase pushes 1 input value and not Span?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to push data into my firebase database. I managed to 1 user input field in. However now I am trying to have a span value in my database (which hanges its number based off a slider which controls it)   This is the error which refers to my writeData function (down below)

```
Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'Exercise.setAm'
```

I have these two values which i get from the html:

```
const exerciseName = document.getElementById("exercise-search");
 const setAmount = document.getElementById("dynamicSet").innerHTML;
```

The exerciseName works fine and I see the result back in my DB:

[image: DB]

However my span doesnt seem to work here is my JS and the span field:

```
function writeData(){
    firebase.database().ref("Exercise").set({
        nameExercise: exerciseName.value,
        setAm: setAmount.value,
    })
}

<span id="dynamicSet"></span>
```

Do you see where I m going wrong? I also tried without innerHTML or without and value and without..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `setAmount`, not `setAmount.value`.

> `const exerciseName = document.getElementById("exercise-search");`

Here you set `exerciseName` to an element

> `const setAmount = document.getElementById("dynamicSet").innerHTML;`

But here you set `setAmount` to the innerHTML of an element.

So, apples and oranges:

Your first variable is set to the DOM representation an HTML element, so it will have various properties,

But your second variable is set to the string value of the innerHTML of a different element -- and as a string, it won't have those DOM properties.

Comment: That is insane! I tried almost every combination but that. THank you very much for the explenation

Comment: @ZK-2500z Yay! If this answered your question, you can click the √ check on the left, and if it was helpful, you can click the ^ up arrow. This helps show other users whether the question was answered and/or helpful.